# Right after Birth

Tags: word-meaning

> For a long time, psychologist thought infants were colorblind right after birth.

What does *right* mean in this sentence?

Comment: Please consult a dictionary and provide more details if you do not understand. [Right](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/right). _adv._

Comment: Here "right" means "just" . In other words, can say "just after birth"

Answer (score 2):

"Right," in this sentence, means "immediately."

In this frame, the word "right" serves as an adverb of indefinite frequency. Common examples of adverbs of indefinite frequency are "always," "generally," "uncommonly," "seldom," and, yes, "*immediately*." These contrast with adverbs of *definite* frequency, among which lie "daily," "weekly," and "yearly." Adverbs of *indefinite* frequency usually go in the mid position of a sentence, though they may also be placed at the beginning or end of a sentence, as evidenced here: "Right" is placed after the main verb and exists as a part of the tripartite adverbial whole that completes the sentence.

So, while we might have an interesting debate about whether "right," contextualized here as being a modifier of an instance proceeding directly after an event so definitive as birth, may qualify as an adverb of *definite* frequency (hmm, possible stack question...), it is here firmly synonymous with "immediately."

Answer (score 1):

It means immediately after birth.

[Here is the Merriam-webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one%20right%20after%20the%20other)

It says, **one right after another = very close together in time**.

Comment: Questions that can be answered quickly using a dictionary are [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Answering such questions is discouraged.  - [From Review](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/45088)